# MFC tooltips, GetDlgItemText does not return the text to use for tooltip

Tags: mfc, tooltip

I recently have been adding tooltips to each dialog item in my application. Prior to adding each to a string resource I wanted to do it in hardcoded text so I can change it easily as I am writing them. Now it has come time to pull strings from the resource files and it seems that I cannot get one to come out and display as a tooltip.

The code below produces a blank tooltip. Though if I replace tmpStr with a real string such as [_T("Tool Tip Text")] it works fine.

Code:

```
BOOL CCustomDialog::OnToolTipText( UINT id, NMHDR * pNMHDR, LRESULT * pResult )
{
    TOOLTIPTEXT *pTTT = (TOOLTIPTEXT *)pNMHDR;
    UINT nID = pNMHDR->idFrom;

    if (pTTT->uFlags & TTF_IDISHWND)
    {
        nID = ::GetDlgCtrlID((HWND)nID);
    }
    if(nID)
    {

        CString tmpStr;
        if( nID == IDC_BUTTON1)
        {
            GetDlgItemText(IDS_BUTTON1_TT, tmpStr);
            _tcsncpy_s(pTTT->szText, tmpStr, _TRUNCATE);
        }
        *pResult = 0;
        return TRUE;
    }
    return FALSE;
}
```

What could be the cause of this?

EDIT: If I put the controls ID of the control I wish to display a tooltip on it, it works and shows the controls description as the text. If I add a String resource in the resource file that the control is located in, the string resource will not come out as a tooltip.

So it seems that this is only a problem with the String resources?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the following section of code

```
    if( nID == IDC_BUTTON1)
    {
        GetDlgItemText(IDS_BUTTON1_TT, tmpStr);
        _tcsncpy_s(pTTT->szText, tmpStr, _TRUNCATE);
    }
```

It looks like you have a button with an ID of `IDC_BUTTON1` with an associated text string in your resource file with ID of `IDS_BUTTON1_TT`.

If that's true, then you need to use `tmpStr.LoadString(IDS_BUTTON1_TT)` to get the text. Don't use `GetDlgItemText()` unless you want the text of the button control, then you need to use it's ID of `IDC_BUTTON1` instead. So, do it like this

```
    if( nID == IDC_BUTTON1)
    {
        tmpStr.LoadString(IDS_BUTTON1_TT);
        _tcsncpy_s(pTTT->szText, tmpStr, _TRUNCATE);
    }
```